# Windows Remote Desktop display on local monitor as well?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I use Windows Remote Desktop (win10) to log on a PC from a remote PC over local network. The monitor switches to lock screen then on the original PC. However, I like to display on the original (physically connected) monitor the same image as on the remote PC (that is logged on and working on the original PC).

After reading a lot of posts here I learned that RD allows control by a single user only. Suggestions range from patching some dll (not an option) over using remote assistance (no internet, only local network) to third party software like team viewer (sometimes mentioned to be slower).

However, I don't want to log on the same PC with multiple users. I only want to display on the original monitor what is streamed to the remote operator. The guy in front of the original monitor does not need to do any input, but likes to see the display.

Is that possible with remote desktop?

Comment: How about using something like RealVNC or UltraVNC?  It allows multiple connections and everyone can control the PC.

Comment: @cup Yes, a third party software is possibly the final solution, but the question is if I can get there without installing something new/additional.

Comment: As far as I remember remote assistance should also work without internet connection. That is as far as I know the only Win10 built-in remote feature that works the way you want.

Comment: It just depends on how many remotes you want.  If you just want one remote, then remote assistance will work.  If you need more than one then use VNC.  Also remember to invoke the share option otherwise every remote that comes on will kick off the other remotes.